# Java objectInputStream back to java class

Tags: java, file, io, inputstream

I'm new to java, and this is just my learning code. I got a problem. I've send array of persons into file,

```
 try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("person.ser"))) {
        for (Person person : persons) {
            oos.writeObject(person);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
    }
```

and now I want to get just two top Persons back to new Person Class array (Stupid, but i just want to learn how to work with files) And don't actually know how.
I tried something like this

```
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("person.ser")))
   {
        Person[] humans = new Person[2];
        humans[0] = new (Person) ois.readObject();
        humans[1] = new (Person) ois.readObject();

   } 
     catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

But it doesnt work. Can someone help ? I think there is just some little mistake.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work", precisely. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead. If it throws an exception, post its stack trace. If you have a compilation error, post the complete and exact error message (and read it). Hint: `new ` is used to call a constructor.

Comment: I cant even compile it, it says < Identifier > expected

Comment: Oh, i got it . It works now without the " new " . I thought i have to somehow create the object before inserting from file.

Comment: I suggest you serialize the `persions` collection.

Comment: May I suggest, if you decide to return with another question at a later date, you review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
humans[0] = new (Person) ois.readObject();
humans[1] = new (Person) ois.readObject();
```

With

```
humans[0] = (Person) ois.readObject();
humans[1] = (Person) ois.readObject();
```